# why isn't the probability of this event$\frac{18}{216}$?

Tags: probability

I've been asked to find the probability of getting a sum of 13 when 3 dies are rolled.
Now they are $3* ^6C_1$ possible events and the favorable ones are
$(1,6,6), (3,5,5),(4,5,4),(3,4,6)(2,5,6)$
and each die can take on any of these values so the probability must be
$\frac{15}{21}$

why is this wrong.

Comment: Where does your $18$ come from?

Comment: I ment 15, sorry

Comment: You can produce $\binom{n}{k}$ by typing `$\binom{n}{k}$`, which is easier to read than your $^nC_k$ notation, particularly when you are multiplying $\binom{n}{k}$ by a number.  Also, you can use `$\cdot$` to produce $\cdot$.

Answer (score 2):

Think about how many ways you can get each of those events.

(1,6,6)(6,1,6)(6,6,1) (3 combinations, 3!/2!)

(2,5,6)(2,5,6)
(5,2,6)(5,6,2)
(6,2,5)(6,5,2) (6 combinations, 3!)

What do you get when you do the rest of them?

Answer (score 2):

You miscounted:

The first $(3)$ choices that you listed each have a repeated number, and so yield $(3)$ choices for which of the $(3)$ dice represents the different number.

The last $(2)$ choices that you listed each have $(3)$ distinct numbers, and so yield $(3! = 6)$ choices, for how the three dice will represent the numbers.

$$(3 \times 3) + (2 \times 6) = 21.$$

---

An alternative approach is that if the first die is $k$, then the sum of the 2nd and 3rd dice must be $(13 - k)$, which can occur in $(k)$ ways.

Therefore, the enumeration is

$$\frac{1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6}{6^3}.$$